# hideDefaultActions attribute of lightning:datatable is not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a requirement where i need to hide "wrap text and clip text" default action options in lightning datatable. However, it doesn't seems to work for me. Actually, tried a lot of permutations and combinations apart from what mentioned in documentation.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation

Sample code that i am using:

```
fieldInfo.forEach(function (field) {
        let obj = {};
        obj.label = field.fieldLabel;
        // Check for reference fields.
        if (field.fieldApi.indexOf('.') !== -1) {//If exists
            modifiedCols.push(field.fieldApi);
            field.fieldApi = field.fieldApi.replace('.', '');
        }
        obj.fieldName = field.fieldApi;
        obj.iconName = 'utility:date_time';
        obj.type = field.fieldType;
        obj.typeAttributes = {
            currencyCode: 'EUR'
        }
        obj.hideDefaultActions= true;
        columns.push(obj);
    })
```

Is there anyone for whom this worked ? Checked on stackExchange (check below comments), it is not working for others as well ? Is this a bug?

Comment: It is working for me. Can you paste some more code or paste a playground link with  sample code that shows your issue?

Comment: Well that weird, Actually i have a lot of code that i can't put here. However, i will cross check with sample codes in playground again. And, if it still doesn't work, will give playground link.

Comment: for example, on this one (from the doc) https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/e922d55d950b9529e93147cdb945d77b636a6ce9/edit you can modify the header in `withRowActions.js` to get `{ label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name', hideDefaultActions : true },` and it works

Comment: On click of header, i am getting this error.
"TypeError: element.getAttribute is not a function"

The same is happening on my playground as well.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/jC5CoMUYi/1/edit

Comment: That's odd, Its working for me (I just removed your `//`). Can you try with a different browser? (maybe is a browser / version issue)

Comment: I am getting this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/06P3a.png

Regarding Chrome version: it is Version 79.0.3945.130

Comment: Raised separate question on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This flag is in the Summer 20 release. So that is why this would work for some orgs and not others currently. Looks like all orgs should be upgraded by mid July 20.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_lwc_components.htm

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Thanks for answering.